Can't debug Pro*C code running inside Docker with CLion
I'm starting to give maintenance to some legacy code written with Oracle Pro*C language and I'm not able to debug it inside CLion. I've tried the setup from this answer added LINES=YES to my makefile and noticed that indeed the .cc files generated from the .pc have the #line directive added to them but still I'm not able to debug it. I can however debug parts of the code that are directly written in C++ with the following setup:
Build the code inside docker container:
docker exec -it mycontainer /bin/bash
cd /path/to/coderoot
make

Inside the docker container, I start gdbserver:
gdbserver 0.0.0.0:9999 my_program --program_args

The Pro*C codes are unavailable for breakpoints when the code is running:

Showing the message The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is associated with this line.
In CLion I've created a Debug configuration to connect to remove debug server:

Notice that I've mapped my local dirs to the remote dirs (inside docker container)
But in the end CLion only sees the code from C++ files of the project and not from my Pro*C code. So is there any missing configuration, in makefiles for example? My question then is how to debug Pro*C code running inside Docker with CLion?
